# Cant install Ubuntu 12.04.4 on Lenovo T61 Nvidia Quadro NVS 140M

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, lenovo, system-installation

I have problem with my laptop and Ubuntu 12.04.4. I want install this OS on my Lenovo ThinkPad `T61` with Nvidia `Quadro NVS 140M` but i cant because screen is crashed.

The pictures is what I see when I turn on Live Mode:

[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have been experiencing similar graphics glitches on the exact same computer model (as described in https://askubuntu.com/questions/400044/nvidia-x-server-flickers-hangs-and-segfaults-on-start-up).

The gist of it is to try to find a way to not use the Nvidia proprietary drivers, but some fallback driver, in the hope to switch on the display. Also try to use older kernels when possible (they seem to behave better with older hardware).

Alternatively, you could use the [Alternate install CD](http://mirror.anl.gov/pub/ubuntu-iso/CDs-Xubuntu/12.04/release/). For Xubuntu, the `.iso` image that you'd need to download would be called [xubuntu-12.04.3-alternate-i386.iso](http://mirror.anl.gov/pub/ubuntu-iso/CDs-Xubuntu/12.04/release/xubuntu-12.04.3-alternate-i386.iso). The advantage of this image is that it doesn't require to load `X` to allow you to perform the system installation. Once the system is installed, you can use the workaround described in [the above question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/400044/nvidia-x-server-flickers-hangs-and-segfaults-on-start-up) to load `X`.